# FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder, error: post no longer available

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I am using the Facebook sdk to share a link.
the post share is well generated, but when i click on post, nothing happened and a toast is displayed:
"this post is no longer available, it may have been removed"

it gives me no error, just this toast.

i m using basic code from the sdk:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                    .setLink(mStationLink)
                    .setDescription(mTextToShare)
                    .setPicture(mImageUri)
                    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

did someone come accross this?

thanks

Comment: What is the link you share? And are you prefilling the description?

Comment: the link is classic link http://http://www.977music.com, the dialog generated by the sdk is fine, but as soon as i click post, i have a toast saying: "this post is no available..."

Comment: Ok I had my code in a fragment, i removed my fragment and use an activity only, and now it is working...